# how to make a div go on top of a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created an auto suggest script that i will use on my site. The problem is that in the manual i created the auto suggest from, they use a `div` that will have the relevant results.

When i use the div it overrides all my page and corrupts its order. 
I am looking for a way to make the `DIV` show on top of the page.

the code - has some pseudo code.

```
//function that uses jquery and ajax to update the autosuggest elements on key up
<input type="text" name="field1" />
<div name="auto_suggest"> </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){

    var search_term = $(this).val();
    $.post('shit5.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function(){
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.autosuggest').val(result_value);
            $('.result').html('');

        });
    });

});
});
```

Comment: could you post sample to jsfiddle

Comment: Can't you just use the [autocomplete jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Please post the script that you mention "I have created an auto suggest script"

Comment: Saw your edit now, updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your edited question (with the $.post code) i see you have a keyup listener on the `.autosuggest`. I think it should be on the input instead:

```
$('input[name=field1]').keyup(function(){
```

And then just give a class to `.autosuggest` with the CSS you need.
If you want to do this with jQuery you can have:

```
$('div[name=auto_suggest]').css({
   'position' : 'absolute',
   top: '0px',
   left: '0px'
});
```

But the best is to make a class with that CSS and add/remove it to the div. The div should be hidden from the beginning I suppose.

EDIT:

To position it near the input field you can also use this:

```
$('input[name=field1]').keyup(function(){
    var thisposition = $(this).position();
    ...
```

and then assigne that position to `.autosuggest` like:

```
$('div[name=auto_suggest]').css({
   'position' : 'absolute',
   top: eval (thisposition.top - 15) + 'px',
   left:thisposition.left + 'px',
});
```

Comment: hello and thank you very much for your answer. it does put it on top of the text but the problem is that it kicks it to the left top of the page. isnt there any option to leave the div where it has been before and keep the on top?

Comment: @Anton.P, sure. If the position worked before just replace the `$('input[name=field1]').keyup(function(){`. It is useful to make a fiddle with it so we can see it live, if you can.

Comment: @Anton.P made a "EDIT" in my answer about positioning the div, please check.

Comment: @Sergio: It would be better if you assigned a `position:relative` to `.autosuggest` and then position the suggestions relative to that. It will be easier and not require a javascript variable to store the position, as CSS can easily handle this.

Comment: @Harsh, yes true. I was going to suggest OP to post html markup for a more exact answer but it was accepted so it might have been what he looked for.

Comment: @Sergio: I think that the OP "got it working", but it's not the best way. Hope the OP is listening.

Comment: @Anton.P, Harsh has a suggestion I also agree with, please check it also.

Comment: @Sergio his solution did not work for me... it pushed the other text down and did not appear under the text box...

Comment: @Anton.P without html in your question is difficould to help you more, I dont know how your html is...

Comment: @Sergio i understand my friend. the most important part is that it works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it gives a bit animation for the page :

```
$('div[name=auto_suggest]').css({'position' : 'absolute'}).animate({top: '0px',left: '0px'}, 1000);
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your answer, i did not understand where to put it?